# Не работает событие конец скролл

Tags: javascript, html, css

`alert(1)` - для того чтобы узнать вообще работает ли жава с. (сейчас работает. (т.е. выводится алерт 1))

`alert(2)` - для того чтобы узнать вообще работает событие прокуртки (сейчас не работает)

`alert(3)` - тоже не работает

```js
 alert(1);
      $(window).scroll(function() 
        {alert(2);
            if($(window).scrollTop()+$(window).height()>=$(document).height()){
        $("#sh").html("555555555555555555555555555555555");
     alert(3);
      }
    });
```

```html
fdfsdf
<br><br><br><br>
<div id ="sh">ffff</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br>ccc<br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br>ccc<br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br>ccc<br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br>ccc<br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br>ccc<br><br><br>
```

Comment: код в сниппете работает.

Comment: Может быть забыли про `jQuery`? Добавьте `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Блиин спасибо вам! я Забыл подключить jquery))))))))))

Comment: Опубликовать ответом или будем закрывать вопрос?

Comment: Опубликовать ответом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо подключить библиотеку `jQuery`. Для этого достаточно в коде прописать строку:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jque‌​ry.min.js"></script>
```

После этого Ваш код полностью заработает.

```js
// alert(1);
$(window).scroll(function() {
  // alert(2);
  if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height()) {
    $("#sh").html("55555555555555555");
    alert(3);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

fdfsdf
<br><br><br><br>
<div id="sh">ffff</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br>ccc<br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br>ccc<br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br>ccc<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>ccc<br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br>ccc<br><br><br>
```